# SQL Server ROUND based on decimal values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to to round the decimal values in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I need to round the value based on the decimal points.

**Logic**

If the decimal value greater than or equal to 0.5 then it should be rounded to the nearest upper number.

If the value is lesser than 0.5 then the value should be rounded to nearest lower number.

I can't use neither upper alone nor lower alone. It should be based on the value.

For example:

- if the data comes as 1.569 it should be rounded to 2 (i.e. 1.5 to 1.99)
- if the data comes as 1.321 it should be rounded to 1 (i.e. 1.01 to 1.49)

Comment: If you had put your [question's title into Google and searched](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SQL+SERVER+ROUND+based+on+decimal+values), one of the top links probably would have been the [SQL Server documentation for the `ROUND` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx). This question does not represent a lot of effort to solve the issue before asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use round Function

```
 Example select convert(int,(ROUND(1.5,0)))
 o/p 2
```

For Info Please Refer This Link.......

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ROUND` function

```
SELECT ROUND(data) FROM table
```